# How to set --num-executors in dataproc cluster

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

We have a dataproc cluster with 10 Nodes and unable to understand how to set the parameter for --num-executor for spark jobs.

Below are the points which are confusing -

- Can we have less executor than number of worker nodes. If yes what will happen to idle worker nodes.
- Can we have more executor than number of worker nodes. where additional executor will run ?
- Can we run more than 1 spark application running using 1 executor per node ?
- Can we run 1 spark application using more than 1  executor per node ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An executor is just a Java process running running on their own JVM on some machine somewhere.

To answer your questions:

- **Can we have less executor than number of worker nodes. If yes what will happen to idle worker nodes.**

  - Yes you can. That just means that the idle worker nodes won't have this Java process running on there.
- **Can we have more executor than number of worker nodes. where additional executor will run?**

  - Yes you can, provided a single worker node can host your 2 JVMs (enough memory/cpu/...) and your resource manager can handle it. The resource manager will decide which node will be hosting the additional executor process.
- **Can we run more than 1 spark application running using 1 executor per node?**

  - This means that you'll have more than 1 executor on a single worker node, so same as point 2.
- **Can we run 1 spark application using more than 1 executor per node ?**

  - This means that you'll have more than 1 executor on a single worker node, so same as point 2.

Hope this helps!